# Countplot function does not work on binned data

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-science

So I have been trying to distribute the data into bins and then use the countplot function on it. But it gives me an error. The binning part of the code seems to be working fine, the problem might be with the countplot function. It would be great if you could suggest how to correct the following.
ps: This might seem trivial, but I'm new to data science.

```
binned=pd.cut(lab3['Survived'],[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80])
p = sns.countplot(x='Survived',data=binned, hue='Survived')
```

The Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-67a29c8aa363> in <module>()
      1 labels = [0-10,11-20]
      2 binned=pd.cut(lab3['Survived'],[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80])
----> 3 p = sns.countplot(x='Survived',data=binned, hue='Survived')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
    151                 if isinstance(var, str):
    152                     err = "Could not interpret input '{}'".format(var)
--> 153                     raise ValueError(err)
    154 
    155             # Figure out the plotting orientation

ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Survived'
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.cut()` returns a `Series` object (and does not return your original `DataFrame` with a new column. Therefore, if you plot `binned` it tries to plot the `Series` and cannot find your original column `Survived`.

You can add the binned Series to your original dataframe:

```
lab3.assign(binned=pd.cut(lab3['Survived'],[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]))
```

I guess plotting will work as expected afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your code.

If `lab3['Survived']` is binary (i.e. yes or no), then there is no need to bin it. It is already in 2 bins.

However, you are trying to assign these ranges to the bins: `[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]`

Those look like ages to me. I believe what you want instead is something like this:

```
lab3['binned'] = pd.cut(lab3['Age'], [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80])
```

That creates a new column in the dataframe which stores each row's corresponding bin.

Now pass it to `countplot()` with the following:

```
p = sns.countplot(x=lab3['binned'], hue=lab3['Survived'])
```

Cheers!